# How to keep an item at the top of a ListBox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, listbox, scroll

I have some headers with some items underneath in a list box, however when my user scrolls down the list box I would like the headers to stay at the top of the list box until a new header comes along and pushes it down.

My header is in the form of a grid, and all the other items are StackPanels.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one header and some items under that you may use two different Grids. In the first grid you can put your headers and second grid you can put your listbox.

However, if you have more than one header you may use LongListSelector. Have a look at the following tutorial. I hope it helps you . 
http://students.cec.wustl.edu/~acm/hackathon/LongListSelectorTutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a `LongListSelector` to me. There's a bit of work to be done but [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj244365(v=vs.105).aspx) shows how to set it up.